# How can I use a custom template to load custom post type posts based on a post_meta value

Tags: custom-post-types, post-meta, page-template

I have a CPT which saves a location and and its slug into `wp_postmeta` table. The location is selected from a dropdown in CPT edit page and it is not a taxonomy.

Now I want to create a custom template which needs to understand the value I am passing through the URL such as `http://example.com/location/himachal-pradesh`.

The part `himachal-pradesh` is my location slug and I want to pull posts which has the same value in `wp_postmeta` table.

I have created a custom template and can use it to create a new page (`http://example.com/location`), but it will actually have the location slug which is dynamic for each location.

What is the right way to achieve this?

Comment: What you write about is a typical use of custom taxonomy.  Replace the custom field `location` to custom taxonomy, this will improve performance.

Comment: Thank you for you quick reply. Yes, that is what I will do if there is no other straight forward way. Just wanted to know if there is! :)

Comment: The use of a custom field for that is possible, but very very inefficient. If you are going to search or filter posts by some information, it is better to save it as taxonomy.